# How to create common toolbar for all instance in ckeditor

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I have a multiple ckeditor instance and each instance is creating one toolbar. In my case i want only one toolbar for all instance .

`editor = CKEDITOR.replace("editor1")`

I am creating ckeditor in this way.

Please give me a solution.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: I'm working on survey js which has many questions in it.Each question has a seperate editor. Each editor in it has a seperate toolbar for it. But I need a common toolbar of all the editors.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the plugin sharedspace and add two divs (top and bottom):

```
<div id="top"></div>
<textarea name="editor1">Editor One </textarea>
<textarea name="editor2">Editor Two </textarea>
<div id="bottom"></div>

 CKEDITOR.replace(
  'editor1',
  {
    toolbar : [{name: 'Copy', items: ['Copy', 'Paste']}],
    extraPlugins:'sharedspace',
    removePlugins: 'maximize,resize',
    sharedSpaces: {
      top: 'top',
      bottom: 'bottom'
    },
  });


CKEDITOR.replace(
  'editor2',
  {
    toolbar : [{name: 'Format', items: ['Bold']}],
    extraPlugins:'sharedspace',
    removePlugins: 'maximize,resize',
    sharedSpaces: {
      top: 'top',
      bottom: 'bottom'
    },
  });
```

Example:

https://codepen.io/edsonperotoni/pen/YzzLgON

Reference:

https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/examples/sharedspace.html